# Как по странице в браузере найти определенную форму в коде?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Есть очень большой веб проект, как мне найти, например, эту форму в коде? Пользуюсь intellij idea. На форму нужно добавить одно поле, но искать ее вручную в проекте нереально просто.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае никак. Этой формы может не быть в Java коде.

Можно попробовать так:

1. Открываете консоль браузера и находите эту форму
2. Ищите какие-нибудь строковые уникальные идентификаторы (id, name, action...)
3. Запускаете в идее поиск строки по проекту

Comment: Вы правы, формы в xml. Через консоль браузера нахожу имя элемента, делаю поиск по модулю, но что-то все не то открывает..